# Does eventstore require event sourcing?

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

Lately, i've come across the term 'EventStore', i've read many articles, which states that Event Store is used for storing event and support querying events. But i can't find any usage of it out of the context Event Sourcing. Is EventSourcing a must went using EventStore? If not, can you give me some context which i can use it without the EventSourcing?

Comment: You might also see "event stores" being used where a solution wants a durable message queue.

Answer (score 2):

`EventStoreDB` and other databases & libraries out there are purpose built for doing *event-sourcing* (as in using events as the state of the system)
so yes, in theory, you would use them when doing *event-sourcing* because they provide fundamental structure & indexes needed to build *event-sourced* systems.

You can use them in other ways, with the same caveats you would have when using a relational database as a document store for instance.